# Readout JSON data in different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am absolutely new at this. The plan is to show the data from the JSON file in different divs, because I want to style the divs in different ways.

1) First I want to read out a single line of my JSON, for example:

The HTML:

```
<div>
    <div data-filter="EX_01_Dates"></div>
    <div data-filter="EX_01_Name"></div>
    <div data-filter="EX_01_City"></div>
</div>
```

And the JSON:

```
var data={"events":[
        {
            "id": EX_01,
            "Name":"Event 1",
            "City":"City 1",
            "Dates":"13-09-2015",
        },
]}
```

2) Second, I want this with different data blocks.

```
var data={"events":[
        {
            "id": EX_01,
            "Name":"Event 1",
            "City":"City 1",
            "Dates":"13-09-2015",
        },
        {
            "id": EX_02,
            "Name":"Event 2",
            "City":"City 2",
            "Dates":"15-09-2015",
        }
]}
```

Thats my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sh3mwt7/). Hope someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
var data={"events":[
    {"id": "EX_01", "Name":"Event 1", "City":"City 1", "Dates":"13-09-2015" },
    {"id": "EX_02", "Name":"Event 2", "City":"City 2", "Dates":"15-09-2015" }
]};

data["events"].forEach(function(elem) {
    for(var key in elem) {
        var filter = [elem["id"], "_", key].join("");
        $("div[data-filter='" + filter + "']").text(elem[key]);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <div data-filter="EX_01_Dates"></div>
    <div data-filter="EX_01_Name"></div>
    <div data-filter="EX_01_City"></div>
</div>

<div>
 <div data-filter="EX_02_Dates"></div>
    <div data-filter="EX_02_Name"></div>
    <div data-filter="EX_02_City"></div>
</div>
```

Read about [Array forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to learn how they work!

Comment: Great! Thats it!! Thx for help!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you use **[jsrender](http://www.jsviews.com/)** for this purpose, there are alot of great articles about it out there. I found the article below very helpful if you dont understand http://www.jsviews.com hope this helps..

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882454.aspx

Comment: Thx for the tip! jsrender looks really interesting, I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not clear what exactly you are doing here.

```
<div id="EX_01">
    <div data-filter="EX_01_Dates"></div>
    <div data-filter="EX_01_Name"></div>
    <div data-filter="EX_01_City"></div>
</div>

<div id="EX_02">
    <div data-filter="EX_02_Dates"></div>
    <div data-filter="EX_02_Name"></div>
    <div data-filter="EX_02_City"></div>
</div>
```

your javascript code which is now jquery added

```
    var data={"events":[
        {
            "id": EX_01,
            "Name":"Event 1",
            "City":"City 1",
            "Dates":"13-09-2015",
        },
        {
            "id": EX_02,
            "Name":"Event 2",
            "City":"City 2",
            "Dates":"15-09-2015",
        }
]}

$("#EX_01").find("div:nth-child(1)").html(data.events[0].Dates);
$("#EX_01").find("div:nth-child(2)").html(data.events[0].Name);
$("#EX_01").find("div:nth-child(3)").html(data.events[0].City);

$("#EX_02").find("div:nth-child(1)").html(data.events[1].Dates);
$("#EX_02").find("div:nth-child(2)").html(data.events[1].Name);
$("#EX_02").find("div:nth-child(3)").html(data.events[1].City);
```

you can work around more for dynamic creation or selection of html elements

Comment: Hi. I have tested my fiddle with your script update, but it dont work for me ;(. The "data-filter" was an example to show, that I want to talk to each line of my json.